# In Eclipse using libgdx, what does "project description file is missing" mean?

Tags: java, libgdx, eclipse

In a sudden case of nostalgia, I switched my eclipse workplace from my working libgdx projects to an older one. After looking through my old stuff I had some problems switching it back, since I didn't import it right. After I got that working, I cant run my libgdx desktop projects anymore. It says it couldn't load the Spritesheet anymore: After googling a little, I was told to make sure the Android asset folder is linked to the desktop project, which it is.

I then noticed that one of the project folders is closed (I've got Project-android,Project-core,Project-desktop and just Project) The folder project was closed and when trying to open it, it gave me the following error:

> The project description file (.project) for 'Projekt Stella' is missing. This file contains important information about the project. The project will not function properly until this file is restored.

The thing is I made sure that this file is still in the folder which it is... so now I have no idea how to get this working. Any ideas?

Edit: The project works fine in Android studio. Its just not working in Eclipse.

Comment: The best solution is to [stop using Eclipse forever](http://www.ihateeclipse.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to re-create project with libGDX setup tool and copy all source code and assets into it from old project. .project file is file that contains information about project Eclipse should know. Do you use Gradle? If so, do you import project into Eclipse as Gradle Project (right) or as Eclipse Project (wrong)? And it's pretty bad idea to use Android Studio and Eclipse simultaneously. Both generate own special files that no one except IDE needs.

Comment: Asses ;).....I think you meant assets.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan lol, edited